# how to get current timestamp when using ps in a bash script?

Tags: bash, unix, timestamp, ps

So I am writing a shell script that gets all the current processes running, and pipes them into grep to filter out the ones I need.

But I also need it to give me a timestamp Either when the PS occurs, or when the process was started, it doesnt matter, I just need A time. All the processes just take fractions of seconds.

My command is this:

```
ps -U USERNAME -o rss=MEM,comm=CMD,pid=PID
```

I tried going like this:

```
ps -U USERNAME -o rss=MEM,comm=CMD,pid=PID, start=START
```

but that just gives me a time like hh:mm:ss. I need something more precise than this. Timestamps are ideal.

Any ideas?

Comment: isn't this a question for http://superuser.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I didnt know that existed...lol I will move it there, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

does the following satisfy your need?

```
date; ps -U USERNAME -o rss=MEM,comm=CMD,pid=PID
```

Comment: Why did I not think of that...Yes it works if I do date+%s.%N :)